# xml parsed result pass through Geopoint() ,problem in number format

Tags: android

I have done xml parsing and store result as latitude and longitude in an StringArray and using `for loop` I store result of lat and longitude in a string named "lat" and "longi"  I want to pass these points through GeoPoint() for showing in a map,now the problem is now that i have 43 items in array: "sitesList.getLatitude().size()" when i use in our for loop it force close it is showing only 20 items  show when i hard coated it then it is showing all lat long in map so now my qus is how to show all 43  position in mymap???

```
      **if i use this then force close and gives number format exceptions...**
      **// for (int i = 0; i < sitesList.getLatitude().size(); i++)**


            for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
         name = sitesList.getLatitude().get(i);
         name1 = sitesList.getLongitude().get(i);
         Log.i("array_spinner" + i, name);
         Log.i("longitiitude"+i,name1);
         point = new GeoPoint((int) (Double.parseDouble(name) * 1E6),
                    (int) (Double.parseDouble(name1) * 1E6));
                     OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, "Tomorrow ", 
                     "(M gives Bond his mission in Daimler car)");
                     itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
    }
```

Comment: try to print the value of sitesList.getLatitude().get(i) and sitesList.getLongitude().get(i)

Comment: use sitesList.getLatitude().get(i).trim() to remove any spaces before and after.

Comment: GeoPoint takes integer. Is your problem regarding the parsing solved?

Comment: pls refer to m y updated qus. pls thanks alot

Comment: you are not giving enough information. How do you enter the values in the list. Try to put print statements throughout the code, and check whether it is running as you expect it to. Without seeing the code, only zombies can help you

Answer (score 0):

```
GeoPoint source = new GeoPoint((int) (Double.parseDouble(String_Value_of_Latitude) * 1E6),
                (int) (Double.parseDouble(String_Value_of_Longitude) * 1E6));
        mapData.add(source);
```

I am using the above code for making GEO point for putting over map.
you should pass only string value of Latitude (String_Value_of_Latitude)and longitude (String_Value_of_Longitude) then you got your answer of this question.
I hope it is too helpful to you.

Comment: Check your LogCat file then give me the error and also check the error in conversion or at other point.